# @HandlerChain annotation without XML file

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

Adding a SoapHandler to a server side webservice is possible via the @HandlerChain annotation:

```
@WebService
@HandlerChain(file= "handler-chain.xml")
public class MyWS {
  ...
}
```

However, this requires that the handler chain is defined in a separate XML file.

For a client side Webservice it is possible to do this fully programmatically:

```
final MyWSService service= new MyWSService(url);
service.setHandlerResolver(new MyHandlerResolver());
```

Is there a way to do this fully programmatically for a server side webservice as well? That means without an additional XML file?